# Coding assignment autograder: Checking if a data stream is generated by a particular Markov process

Tags: markov-process

I teach an introductory programming course in which most assignments ship with a set of tests students can use locally on their machine to validate that their code works as intended.

Many years ago we used to give out a programming assignment in which students would ingest a data set and form a Markov process from it. They would then generate data streams from that Markov process as output. (More specifically, the program generates a model of language by predicting the next character of a text based on the $n$-gram that comes before it. They then sample from the process to generate plausible random text. It’s a lot of fun!)

The problem we’re running into is that this assignment is inherently probabilistic and thus not easily autograded, since the output can vary widely from run to run. Standard techniques like “give the students a fixed random number generator to use” don’t easily work here because there is such variability in how the logic can be implemented and many perfectly legitimate strategies would query the random generator in different ways.

This led me to wonder whether there was a statistical method that could be used to analyze the output of the student code and infer whether the sequences generated were produced from the correct Markov model. With enough data generated, it should be possible to build up an “empirical” Markov model $M’$ from the output of the student code. We could then precompute the “correct” or “reference” Markov model $M$ using our own solution.

However, once we have $M$ and $M’$, I’m not sure what the proper method is for determining whether they’re “sufficiently close” that “with very high probability” the student code for forming and sampling from the model is correct. There are some cases that I can easily check for (if there should be a $0$ probability of a transition in $M$, and that transition appears in $M’$, then $M’$ is definitely wrong). However, I don’t have a good sense of how to define what it means for $M$ to be “close” to $M’$, how to quantify the expected “distance” between the reference model $M$ and the empirical model $M’$ is as a function of the model size and amount of data generated, or how to draw a line that says “your code is probably right/wrong because $M’$ is sufficiently/not sufficiently close to $M$.”

Is there a standard way to do this? Or a negative theorem suggesting it isn’t possible?